# Remove default store code from URL

Tags: multistore, url-rewrite, store-view, default

How I can remove store code from default store URL of my website?

**Actually**

```
www.domain.com/it/ **DEFAULT STORE**

www.domain.com/en/ **ENGLISH STORE**
```

**I Need**

```
www.domain.com/ **DEFAULT STORE**

www.domain.com/en/ **ENGLISH STORE**
```

Answer (score 3):

Turn off store code urls in admin

```
admin > stores > configuration > General > Web > Add Store Code to Urls > No
```

run upgrade, static-content-deply and cache clean/flush commands

Answer (score 0):

The `it`, `en` are the store view code, you can config them in `admin->system->store manager->store view->code`, now you can access to the store view either on enabling the code store view in the url in: `admin->system->configuration->Web->Add store code to URLs->Yes`, either to type this in the URL: `www.domaine.com/?___store=en`.

Now if want to remove the code from url, you have to set :`Add store code to URLs->No`, and you can always type it in the URL `www.domaine.com/?___store=en`.

Answer (score -1):

If you have multiple store and want to remove **?___store=**

> Go to \app\code\core\Mage\Core\Model\Store.php line number 1153

// `$storeParsedQuery['___from_store'] = $fromStore === true ? Mage::app()->getStore()->getCode() : $fromStore;`

Just comment it..

Then it will show
http://yoursite.com/en/ or http://yoursite.com/bd/ or your store code

Comment: also Add Store Code to Urls= YES from Magento configuration